# Navigate throught database rows

Tags: php, mysql

i run a image hosting site, and I've run into a problem. I want to make a 2 buttons beside the pic for like "Next image" and "Prev image". Im fairly new to php/mysql and haveing some troubles.

Check out what i got. I use the ID (numbers) to find the correct row, but i have to get the image name also to build the next link. How do I make the below query get the next and prev image names + ids?

```
    $query_next = ("SELECT imageID, image_name FROM images WHERE image_name = '$image_main' ORDER BY imageID DESC LIMIT 1");

    $query_prev = ("SELECT imageID, image_name FROM images WHERE image_name = '$image_main' ORDER BY imageID ASC LIMIT 1");

// next
$next = mysql_query($query_next);
// prev
$prev = mysql_query($query_prev);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($next)) {
    $next = $row['image_name'];
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($prev)) {
    $prev = $row['image_name'];
}
```

The html = > Simple stuff.

```
<a href="http://example.com/view_image/<?=$next?>">Next image</a>
<a href="http://example.com/view_image/<?=$prev?>"> Prev image </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the previous item you want the first row SMALLER than the current id:

```
"SELECT imageID, image_name FROM images WHERE imageID < $current_img_id ORDER BY imageID DESC LIMIT 1"
```

For the next item you want the first row LARGER than the current id:

```
"SELECT imageID, image_name FROM images WHERE imageID > $current_img_id ORDER BY imageID ASC LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: Ah, ok i see. $current_img_id => $row["imageID"]; Right?

Comment: shouldn't imageID>$current_img_id be imageID<$current_img_id for previous image case ?

Comment: LOL dude i got it working with this answer! Thanks mate! The problem was i never execeuted the $currentID variable, when i did it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Your both queries are fetching same images because you are passing same $image_name to them:

Change this:

```
$query_next = ("SELECT imageID, image_name FROM images WHERE image_name = '$image_main_next' ORDER BY imageID DESC LIMIT 1");

$query_prev = ("SELECT imageID, image_name FROM images WHERE image_name = '$image_main_prev' ORDER BY imageID ASC LIMIT 1");
```

and see if that works.

Comment: $image_main is the image's real name. I need to fetch the image name, its always diffrent

Comment: ok...that makes sense. Can you echo the values of $prev and $next that you are getting in your code above? that would help with debugging.

Comment: But dont we have to set the variables?

Comment: No. I am trying to see what values are set for $prev & $next from this: // next
$next = mysql_query($query_next);
// prev
$prev = mysql_query($query_prev);

Comment: in either case, it would be better if you start with a id for the current image and then further perform the prev/next logic.

Comment: ok, then imageID is the image id then image_name is the actual image name, how do i use the id to find the next image but show only the image name?